# Generating letters in Java

Tags: java, letters

I need to generate some business letters in Java, with some dynamic information like address, to,from etc. Remaining letter content would be the same. These letters are not displayed to the user but are directly printed. I know i can do this using Jasper Reports i.e generate pdf & print it. Does somebody have any other suggestions for this?

Comment: Crystal Reports? ;-) I'd suggest to be a little bit more specific in what you're looking for. Is there any reason you'd ditch Jasper in favor of another solution?

Comment: Is it possible to have a pre-defined template in pdf, so that the business user also can define it & then have only the dynamic fields be populated by the code to generate the target pdf

Comment: I propose you think through your requirements and adjust your question accordingly (or close this one and start a new one). Templating is a pretty standard feature in reporting tools like Crystal, BIRT, Jasper, ... The main question most of the times is: is the template editor user-friendly?

Comment: The question is as mentioned to generate business letters with mostly static content & formatting but with some dynamic information like address, to from etc. Although the letter is directly printed, the business user right now provides us the details with formatting in pdf file. One way is for the developer redo all the formatting & content in the report editor & generate the letter, i want to avoid is duplication of report designing. Also i dont want the business user to learn a new tool like Ireport.

Comment: It's a decision that has to be made but in some cases it's better to learn the users how to create the template with the design tool that comes with your reporting system. More so if it involves several templates that change constantly. I can understand what you're talking about though (having a similar situation at work); see my answer for a 'hint' towards a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PDF-tool like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). iText lets you create pdf documents from Java or .NET.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is perfect for the generation. You would probably then use some other library to convert to a printable format and print.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create PDFs, I recommend [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). Examples are available [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook/creation.html#CreateBlankPDF).

Answer (score 0):

If you're up to it, you can use a few freely available libraries to construct your own system where the user can provide the templates in a Word (or Writer) format. Several options are available to do the merging of data with the template but basically it comes down to opening the document as xml and replacing custom tags (or the ones used for the mailmerge function) with the data. You could implement FreeMarker for the custom tags (see [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319674/generating-letters-in-java/7319695#7319695)).
Libraries that cross my mind are:

- OpenOffice API
- Docx4J
- Apache POI

There are plenty of experienced users here on SO for these (and other libraries) so any problem you encounter will surely get a decent followup.

Cheers,
Wim

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your template comments, [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis) might be useful.  They work over top of the OpenOffice API (as per Wivani's response) which can be hard to use directly.